# Is $ \frac{ x^T A A x }{ 1+ x^TAx} $ is upperbounded by the biggest eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I read somewhere that 
$$
\frac{ x^T A A x  }{ 1+ x^TAx}
$$
is bounded by the biggest eigenvalue of $A$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ and it is PSD. Anyone see why this is the case?

Source: Final paragraph, page 2: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-867-machine-learning-fall-2006/lecture-notes/lec6.pdf

Comment: Do you mean $x^TA^TAx$ in the numerator?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.

Comment: I attached the source of the claim.

Comment: The reference you offer assumes that $A$ is positive semidefinite, which makes a difference. TZakrevskiy below is correct about the general case.

Comment: From page 1 of the notes, $A=X^TX$, so its both PSD and symmetric ($A=A^T$)

Answer (score 4):

Unless there are some additional hypotheses, it is false: consider $d=1$ and $A=-1$. Then you want to study the function $$x\to \frac{x^2}{1-x^2},$$which is not bounded on $\Bbb R$.

If we  make an additional hypothesis that $A=A^T\ge 0$ (as was done in the pdf you linked), then you can write $x$ in the orthogonal basis of eigenvectors of $A$: $c_1e_1+\dots+c_ne_n$. Then $$x^TA^TAx = \lambda_1^2c_1^2+\dots+\lambda_n^2c_n^2 ,$$ with $\lambda_j$ being the eigenvalues associated with eigenvector $e_j$. Similarly,
$$x^TAx = \lambda_1 c_1^2+\dots+\lambda_n c_n^2.$$
Now you have a nice little optimisation problem over $\Bbb R^n$ with parameters $\lambda_j$ and variables $c_j$, which should be easy to solve.

Comment: Good point. I also attached the source to the question.

Comment: Sry I forgot to mention: $A$ is psd. updated.